# license info of a deb package

Tags: licensing, dpkg, deb

I am trying to get license information of uninstalled deb packages.
`dpkg --info <package-name>.deb` does not give that information.
Is there any command in ubuntu which will give this info?
(In rpm world rpm -qpi gives that info)

Comment: See also near-duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35044841/how-to-list-all-installed-packages-licences-in-ubuntu/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no simple command that I know of. You can do something like this:

```
dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile foo.deb |tar -xvO ./usr/share/doc/foo/copyright
```

This prints the file to standard output.

*Edit* Hmm, that sounds hard. After a quick perusal of the apt cache on my Debian system, I found some phrases that might be useful:

- "GNU General Public License"
- "the above copyright notice and this permission notice", making sure you unwrap lines first
- "`/usr/share/common-licenses/*`"

  This seems to be the closest to a standard license you'll get, but be careful since often the *packaging* is under a common-license, but the package contents are under a separate license.
- `^License: MPL-1.1 | GPL-2+ | Apache-2.0`

However, some packages (ImageMagick) simply have a free-form license in the copyright file that doesn't really conform to any stock license, except that someone considered it DFSG-approved.

*Update 2012*: This is beginning to change, as the `debian/copyright` file [is now required to be machine-interpretable](http://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/copyright-format/1.0/), so you can look forward to this in the future.

Comment: the copyright file does not have a standard format (i.e license name, license text) which makes it hard to extract that info. Specially if I want to do this for hundreds of packages.

Comment: Hmmm..I guess a foolproof solution does not exist then.

Comment: Update 2015: Many packages [still have not transitioned to machine-readable license files](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35052572/260122). The only online service to check for license metadata is the "Copyright File" link on the package page on https://packages.debian.org/ .